# Distance between recyclerview items

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

This is how my app shows items in RecyclerView.
[image]

This is how it should be looked like.
[image]

What changes can I make to achieve the same?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ln1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/setimage"> 

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="50dp" /> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show your layout xml file. My guess is you're using match_parent instead of wrap_content.

Comment: Thanks.I tried wrapcontent but it solved the problem only 50 parent. At first all the items are shown like in the desired view but when i slide it left ,the new  appearing items are separated like before.

Comment: <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ln1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/setimage">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: Thanks for adding your RecyclerView layout but I was actually asking about the layout for your adapter. Can you add that along with the adapter class as code blocks within your post.

Answer (score 0):

Since the RecyclerView is horizontal in orientation, you need to make the `layout_width` of the  linear layout a fixed value (or `wrap_content`) to remove the unwanted space shown in the image.